Configuring options like --workerLogLevelOverrides when using terraform google_dataflow_flex_template_job
Is it possible to configure logging options such as --workerLogLevelOverrides when using google_dataflow_flex_template_job? Other default dataflow properties like --tempLocation have an option on the google_dataflow_flex_template_job resource.
I tried just adding workerLogLevelOverrides="..." to the parameters map but got the following unrecognized parameter error:
unrecognized dataflow parameter error
